# Ionic apk signing error

Tags: android, ionic-framework, keytool, jarsigner, zipalign

Currently trying to sign my apk which has been built with ionic v2 following the exact procedure advised by ionic in their docs: http://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/guide/publishing.html

But for some reason, I am getting this error when uploading to the play console:
You uploaded an APK with an invalid signature (learn more about signing). Error from apksigner: ERROR: JAR_SIG_NO_SIGNATURES: No JAR signatures

Was surprised to find very little mention of this error (and none in relation to ionic) on google. What is most bizarre is that I was signing apps no problem a few months ago but only encountering this recently. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you uploading `HelloWorld.apk` or `HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk`? What does `jar tvf your.apk META-INF` output?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It appears that the APK you're uploading does not contain any JAR signature files. Typically, these are `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`, `META-INF/<key alias>.SF` and `META-INF/<key alias>.RSA`.

Try producing a signed APK using `apksigner` (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/apksigner.html) which is the endorsed tool for creating signed APKs:

```
zipalign -v -p 4 HelloWorld-release-unsigned.apk HelloWorld.apk
apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.keystore HelloWorld.apk
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my product by modifying the following line in the config.xml file:

```
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" ...
```

to

```
<widget id="br.com.pedcare" ...
```